# Error: A file can't be part of more than one library

Tags: flutter, api, dart, encryption

I imported the API: encrypt 5.0.0, later after writing the class for encrypting and decrypting strings, I get this error:

```
 Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
```

and subsequently the methods are not recognized either:

```
 Error: Getter not found: 'Key'.
  static final key = encrypt.Key.fromLength (32);




Error: Getter not found: 'IV'.
  static final iv = encrypt.IV.fromLength (16);

Error: Method not found: 'AES'.
  static final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter (encrypt.AES (key));

 Error: Method not found: 'Encrypter'.
  static final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter (encrypt.AES (key));
```

The code of the class is :

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;

class Encryption {

  static final key = encrypt.Key.fromBase64('key');
  static final  iv = encrypt.IV.fromBase64('iv');
  static final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key));

  static encryptAES(text) {
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(text, iv: iv);

    print(encrypted.bytes);
    print(encrypted.base16);
    print(encrypted.base64);
    return encrypted;
  }
}
```

would anyone know how to help me solve these problems and be able to successfully encrypt and decrypt some strings in my App? THANKS

Comment: can you try `import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrpyt;` as a import statement.

Comment: the package has already been imported but despite this the error persists.

Comment: how did you import it? can you share the statement.

Comment: import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;                                                 this is my import line

Comment: Please [edit] the information into the question instead of creating illegible comments.

Comment: Please post exact code from a miminal reproducible example.

Comment: sorry I edited the text, can you solve the problem?

Comment: Is there any more to the error message?  Are you certain that it's caused by your use of `package:encrypt`?  I cannot reproduce your problem with the code that you've posted.